# CSV file upload with data validation

Tags: php, sql, csv, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a *.CSV file to the database using PhP.
I can't really make the data validation work with the file upload.
The script should see if the data from certain cells is valid by searching in the db's tables.
    The file should not be uploaded if there are errors!

Here's the code!

```
<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

    include ("connection2.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        $err = 0;

        if ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        {

            while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== false)
            {
                $tid = trim($filesop[0]);
                $beneficiar = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[1])));   
                $locatie = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[2])));
                $localitate = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[3])));
                $judet = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[4])));
                $adresa = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[5])));
                $model = trim($filesop[6]);

                $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM modele WHERE `model` = '".$model."'");
                if (!empty($query)) {
                    $err ++;
                    $msg=$msg."Model error on row $c <br>";
                }

                $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM judete WHERE `nume` = '".$judet."'");
                if (!empty($query)) {
                    $err ++;
                    $msg=$msg."Judet error on row $c <br>";
                }

                $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM beneficiari WHERE `nume` = '".$beneficiar."'");
                if (!empty($query)) {
                    $err ++;
                    $msg=$msg." Beneficiar error on row $c <br>";
                }

                // if (strlen($tid)!==8){
                    // $err ++;
                    // $msg=$msg."TID length error at row $c <br>";
                // }

                $c ++;
            }
            if ($err!==0){
                echo $msg;  echo "ERROR COUNT= ".$err;
                break;
            }

            $c=0;

            while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== false)
            { 
                $tid = trim($filesop[0]);
                $beneficiar = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[1])));   
                $locatie = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[2])));
                $localitate = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[3])));
                $judet = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[4])));
                $adresa = ucwords(strtolower(trim($filesop[5])));
                $model = trim($filesop[6]);

                $qry=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM beneficiari WHERE `nume` = '".$beneficiar."'");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
                    $id_client=$row['id'];
                    echo "Beneficiar=".$row['id'];
                }

                $qry_id_model=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM modele WHERE `model` = '".$model."'");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_id_model)){
                    $id_model=$row['id'];
                    echo "Model=".$row['id'];
                }
                echo "MODEL2:".$id_model;

                $adresa1 = $adresa.", ".$localitate;

                if ($c!==0){

                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO equipments 
                            (id_client, model, tid, beneficiar, adresa, agentie, judet) 
                            VALUES
                        ('$id_client','$id_model','$tid','$beneficiar','$adresa1','$locatie','$judet')");
                }
                $c = $c + 1; 
            }

            if($sql){
                echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recordes <br>";
            }else{
                echo "Sorry! There is some problem.<br>";
            }

            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
        }
        else echo "NOT CSV!";
    }
?>
```

What's wrong here?

When i try to run it the data is not uploaded and no errors are shown, I left errors in the file to test it. Also i uploaded a clean file and also the file is not uploaded. If i break the code in 2 and make 2 separate codes, one to verify and one to upload, the upload works, but i need the verification and the upload to be in the same code. also tried mysql_query in stead of  mysqli_query.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I've added an answer to address a couple of things that immediately appear wrong with your code - however at the moment all we've got to go off is `"it's not working properly"` - some insight as to _what exactly_ isn't working would be helpful.

Comment: @MacroMan when i try to run it the data is not uploaded and no errors are shown, i left errors in the file to test it, also i uploaded a clean file and also the file is not uploaded. If i break the code in 2 and make 2 separate codes, one to verify and one to upload, the upload works, but i need the verification and the upload to be in the same code. also tried mysql_query in stead of  mysqli_query

Comment: `mysql_query` is depreciated and **should not** be used - always use `mysqli_query` - have you tried adding the connection to the method as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: i tried the mysqli_query suggested but nothing changed...nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

The procedural style of `mysqli_query` takes 2 arguments - the connection and the query. You're only passing the query.

You can read the official documentation for the `mysqli_query()` method here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

---

A suggestion as to how to approach this would be something like:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if(!$link)
{
    echo("Unable to connect");
} else {
    if($ret = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM modele WHERE `model` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $model)."'"))
    {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ret);
        echo($data["id"]);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

---

**Important**: Note my use of `mysqli_real_escape_string` in the example above - your current code leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -3):

first of all you should upload this file on a temporary folder and save the file name. Then use [getCSV php function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php) to read properly the file.

Finally you can check if it's all OK, insert on database, and, if not, echo an error message and delete the file (remember we saved the name and we know the static route of the temporary folder).

Hope it helps!

Comment: i dont want to upload any rows if the file has errors

Comment: upload rows? i'm talking to store the file temporary to properly read and check for errors